# In IntelliJ code complete, how can I make the cursor end up inside the parens, not after them

Tags: intellij-idea, parentheses, code-completion

When using code completion for beginner tutorials in IntelliJ, it keeps putting the cursor after the parens, forcing me to hit the left key each and every time.

Using a pipe to represent the cursor: "printl" completes to "println()|" when what I need is "println(|)"

With the second, if you type a " after completion you would get println("") but at the moment what I get is println()""

I know it seems a simple thing but when you have to keep moving your right hand off the keys in order to hit the <- arrow for about 75% of your lines, it becomes the thing that slows you down and gets old really fast.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Live Template with $END$ in between the quotes was exactly what I needed.

Now if I could just figure out either how to edit the stock println() to include the $END$ or make my live template show on the top of the list instead of the bottom.

Having to reach over to select the right template kind of defeats the purpose of making one so I don't need to reach over to move the cursor lol

Answer (score 0):

In the list, you can select on overload of "println" that has some parameters.

If you're printing to stdout, you can alternatively use a live template: type "sout" and press Tab.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ's code completion is context sensitive w.r.t where it places the cursor.

Given the following methods:

```
private void foo() {}

private void bar(String s) {}
```

If I type `fo` and let IntelliJ auto complete `foo()` it will place the cursor after the brackets because IntelliJ knows that `foo()` has no parameters so it assumes that you'll want to move on to something else.

If I type `ba` and let IntelliJ auto complete `bar()` it will place the cursor **inside** the brackets because IntelliJ knows that `bar()` expects a parameter so it assumes that the next thing you'll want to enter is a parameter for `bar()`.

Of course it can get a little confusing when a method is overloaded, and allows for zero or more parameters.

If you are finding that IntelliJ's choice is wrong then you could create a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-templates.html). Here's an example of the `sout` live template:

```
System.out.println($END$);
```

This turns `sout + TAB` into `System.out.println();` and, in accordance with the `$END$` instruction, the cursor is placed **inside** the parantheses.